# Looking for a symbol for Southern USA communism

Tags: communism, north-america

For a [novel I'm writing](http://jj.github.io/hoborg) I'm looking for a symbol, akin to hammer and sickle, that would represent a socialist republic created in Florida plus a but of Alabama and surrounding states. The hammer in the communist symbol represents industrial workers, while the sickle represents peasants so I don't know if at the beginning of the XX century they would mean much in that area. What do you think could be the right symbol? A gun and a scythe? Any help will be appreciated and obviously acknowledged in the novel when published.

**Update**: To make the question more general, how do in general revolutionary countries adapt symbols to their peculiarities, given that the hammer and sickle are a symbol of the Russian revolution and have as origin the two worker classes (factory and farm) that joined to take the revolution to vistory?

**Update+1**: I finally adapted the West Florida flag adding an Angolan machete in maroon (which accounts for the cimarrón origin of many of the natives). Check it out [here](https://github.com/JJ/hoborg/blob/7a60a98b153d7bf0f3f8c20bd34bb7a943984e25/resources/florida%20republic%20icon.png) Thanks a lot for the contributions, it will duly be acknowledged in the book.

Comment: I'd first wonder why did you chose this very particular region of USA and then focus on it. If you find any clues on why would communism grow easier in this region then in others, just use whatever symbolizes these clues. Imho logo of Communist Party USA is a good point to start with.

Comment: In a nutshell, it's an alternate timeline in which the United States lost the Spanish-American war and insurgency was carried over to USA leading to independence of Florida and surrounding areas. So I'd like the symbol to be quintessentially Southern, and obviously non-existent.

Comment: The hammer and sickle was used by southern Communists (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Southern-Worker-1931-09-19.jpg), so you could just use that.

Comment: I see that the plot is fictional enough, so I suggest try image search, click here: https://www.google.hu/search?safe=off&q=communist+usa&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47244034,d.Yms&biw=1300&bih=853&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=hu&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=CS-nUZfyDZHCswax34CoCw and make your own, use ideas. I saw many creative

Comment: I second T.E.D's suggestion of the raised fist. However, I think the symbolism should also depend on a) the republic's attitude to Native Americans (Seminole symbolism perhaps? Didn't find any in Wikipedia) and b) slavery/African Americans. Theoretical socialism/Marxism should be sympathetic to these groups, but of course that might no be the case in practice. Also, is the Republic pro-Spanish/Mexican? Predominantly industrial (hammer) or agricultural (palms? oranges? cotton)?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this question is on topic. However it is intriguing and has certainly generated interesting comments and an answer.

Comment: @DarekWędrychowski: Florida was part of "Spanish" North America. As such, there was a real chance that it would not become part of the USA. The three regions for which this applies are Florida, Texas, and California. Hence I would choose one of these in which to locate a hypothetical "UnAmerica." It's a bit like saying, why did Bogdan Chiemieski start his "depolonization" movement in the Ukraine, as opposed to further west.

Comment: One request I would like to make here: Please edit your question a bit to make it more generally relevant (it wouldn't take much). Questions that can only help yourself are considered too localized.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of Texas and California, but not of Florida, I'll try to read something on the subject, as it's pretty interesting.

Comment: @Jørgen you are absolutely right; it's actually a All Races People's Republic of Florida so native American plus Hispanic symbolism would be right on the mark.

Comment: @TomAu I've updated a bit the question so that it might be useful to other counterfactual writers or just people interested on the history and origin of symbols. Thanks.

Comment: @DarekWędrychowski: Spanish Florida was known as EAST Florida, which is why it is hard for a non-American to find: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Florida.  But the earlier talk about my struggles with Bogdan Chmielski got me to write the "partition" question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on World Building SE

Comment: This question is 3 years old, and the questions are based in history and on topic. It's not so much about world building as about the history of symbols and of ideologies. I would vote for leaving it here, since it's really attracted lots of interesting answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given the area you are choosing to encompass (I'm assuming Florida and perhaps the swamplands of neighboring states), I'd go with an Alligator. That's an animal that today is ubiquitous throughout the peninsula of Florida, and in the southern swampy parts of bordering states.

If you wanted to go with more traditional communist iconography, I'd consider trading the sickle for a curved machete (again due to the large amount of swampland involved). Most iconography I could find likes to either use some kind of theme of a raised fist, or stick to something easily recognized as the old hammer inscribed in a sickle image. I did find one symbol, pruporting to be from the [People's Republic of America](http://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/showthread.php?625299-The-People-s-Republic-of-America-A-communist-USA-AAR) that added a gear to close the circle with the sickle.

I'm only aware of one Marxist-leaning group that ever held any real power in the southern USA. Socialists in Oklahoma were actually quite strong in the state's founding and early history, including having a major hand in drafting the state constitution, until the ill-advised [attempt to take over the federal government](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Corn_Rebellion) in 1917. Their backbone was not the stereotypical urban proletariat, but rather poor farmers. What little symbology I've been able to dig up for their organizations appears to mostly be of the upraised fist variety. I'm guessing the hammer inscribed in a sickle image didn't become prevalent until the successful movement in Russia made it famous at the end of WWI. So for anything prior to WWI, I wouldn't expect to see a hammer and sickle variant used.

Comment: Florida plus "Alabama and a bit of surrounding states." I'd  assume that he means Florida plus "West Florida" (the Gulf coasts of Alabama and Mississippi).

Comment: Correct, but not only; also some buffer territories to the North of the current Florida state.

Answer (score 4):

OK, now that the question is a bit more general I can attempt a brief answer - sorry for mainly citing Wikipedia, from where I am sure you can find better sources if you want to.

First, the [Hammer and sickle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammer_and_sickle) were "conceived during the Russian Revolution". Hence, you might not want to use them if your point of departure is 1898. The article [Symbols of communism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbols_of_communism) has some other symbols.

The article [Flag of the Soviet union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_the_Soviet_Union#Similarities_with_other_flags) has a gallery of other communist flags. The star seems by far to be the most common symbol (and is the symbol used on the most popolous nominally Socialist country today, China)

The [Red flag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_flag_%28politics%29) appears to be the oldest, dating back to at least to the [Revolutions of 1848](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revolutions_of_1848).

[Flags of the Soviet republics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flags_of_the_Soviet_Republics) has more Communist flags, heavily inspired by that of the Soviet union.

Let me finish by some symbolism I found in the above articles:

[image: Angola]

Angola: Cogwheel, machete and star (if you wanted to pick something "off the shelf" (which you probably wouldn't) this would perhaps be the one to use?)

[image: Ireland]

Irish citizens' army: Ursa minor and a plough (and a sword?)

[image: Khiva]

Khiva SSR: Hammer, sickle, star, crescent, and some other thing (utensil? crop?)

[image: Estonia]

Estonian SSR: hammer, sickle, star, and the sea

Comment: I had actually thought about Angola, and might do something along those lines, combining with the actual flag of West Florida, white star on blue.

Answer (score 2):

At the beginning of the 20th century, revolutionary imagery was dominated by a completely different symbol set.  The Red and Black flags were popular, having origins early in the 19th century left.

The star, fist, sabot (wooden shoe) and after 1905 black cat also had a place.

But prior to 1919, revolutionary imagery was not dominated by Bolshevik symbols.  The development of Hammer & Sickle imagery needs to be contextualised in terms of the massive problems the Bolsheviks had in the countryside, for example, exterminating the cream of the rural workers and left-rural peasants movements.

Would this be true of Florida in 1900?  Unlikely.  Look at IWW imagery, same period, revolutionary left politics, American in origin.

Answer (score 1):

I'd think that any breakaway Southern republic--even a Communist one--would somehow acknowledge the Stars and Bars, perhaps with some suitable nod toward racial equality. The Confederate Flag not only has more emotional resonance in the South than any other icon, but Southern socialists might actually find some inspiration in the history of the Confederacy:

> Although southerners rebelled against growing centralization of the
>   federal government, they had no qualms about establishing a strong
>   national state of their own.  Scholars have classified the Confederate
>   central government as a form of "war socialism."  The Confederacy
>   owned key industries, regulated prices and wages, and instituted the
>   most far-reaching draft in North American history.  The Confederacy
>   employed some 70,000 civilians in a massive (if poorly coordinated)
>   bureaucracy that included thousands of tax assessors, tax collectors,
>   and conscription agents.  The police power of the Confederate state
>   was sometimes staggering.  To ride a train, for example, every
>   passenger needed a special government pass…Political scientist Richard
>   Franklin Bensel writes that "a central state as well organized and
>   powerful as the Confederacy did not emerge until the New Deal and
>   subsequent mobilization for World War II. ([source](http://marginalrevolution.com/marginalrevolution/2009/12/another-reason-not-to-be-a-civil-war-revisionist.html))

While we tend to associate the South with states rights and small government, this attitude toward the government is (was?) deeply rooted in shielding itself from Northern policies, not in an attitude toward the value of government per se. This is a major theme in the historiography of Southerners like Andrew Jackson and John Calhoun.

Southern approval of social spending carried through the first half of the 20th century (and [arguably continues to this day](http://www.economist.com/blogs/dailychart/2011/08/americas-fiscal-union)). Never forget that the South was the basis of the New Deal coalition, with the Gulf Coast particularly strong for FDR (darker blue = more Democratic):

[image]

And FDR was the *moderate* candidate heading into 1936. Huey Long, Louisiana born and bred, was known for wanting to "[share the wealth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huey_Long#Share_Our_Wealth)":

> Some historians believe that pressure from Long and his organization
>   contributed to Roosevelt's "turn to the left" in 1935. He enacted the
>   Second New Deal, including the Social Security Act, the Works Progress
>   Administration, the National Labor Relations Board, Aid to Dependent
>   Children, the National Youth Administration, and the Wealth Tax Act of
>   1935. In private, Roosevelt candidly admitted to trying to "steal Long's thunder."

Or as Tyler Cowen puts it:

> One implication is that the United States kept "small government" for
>   an artificially long period of time, due to North-South splits and the
>   resulting inability to agree on what a larger government should be
>   doing.